# Bootstrap typeahead data-source attribute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datasource, typeahead

I´m just trying to do a simple Bootstrap typeahead plugin example in an HTML5 project. I´m trying to provide the sources with data-source attribute in input element. The examples look so easy, but it doesn´t work for me.

It looks like bootstrap is working and the javascript is called. When I type a character in the input the dropdown list is shown but just the first character (not the whole word).

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Rober HTML5 Bootstrap Sample</title>

    <!-- CSS files -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]--> 

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my HTMl5 Bootstrap example!</h1>

    <div class="well">
        <input type="text" class="span3" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4"     placeholder="Introduce un país" 
                       data-source="['Alabama', 'California', 'Marte']" >  
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript files - At the end of the page load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of the data-source attribute is [JSON](http://www.json.org/), which requires double quotes for strings.
Try rewriting it as:

```
data-source='["Alabama", "California", "Marte"]'
```

BTW I'd also add `autocomplete="off"` to the input element to turn off browser autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as:

```
    data-source="[&quot;Alabama&quot;, &quot;California&quot;, &quot;Marte&quot;]"
```